Couldn't access Docker mongo-express from localhost port
I'm new to docker and was trying out something with docker, mongodb, mongo-express.
Below are the commands I executed -
docker network create mongo-network
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --network mongo-network --name mongodb mongo
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb --network mongo-network --name mongo-express mongo-express

Everything worked as expected, no error.
Below are the logs of mongo-express -
> docker logs b44b
Waiting for mongo:27017...
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
Wed Dec 18 11:23:37 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (2/10)
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
No custom config.js found, loading config.default.js
Welcome to mongo-express 1.0.2
------------------------
Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!

Last few lines of logs suggest that mongo-express server is running on port 8081 of localhost. But when I try to access it, it gives me error saying -
This page isn’t working right now
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

What could be causing this issue?

The logs say that it's trying to connect to mongo but you've called your Mongo container mongodb. It's as if it doesn't register your ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER setting and uses the default 'mongo' value.

I changed the container name to "mongo" from mongodb, it doesn't give error any more and says "Welcome to mongo-express 1.0.2.... Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081". But when opened localhost:8081 in chrome/edge, its still giving the same error "This page isn’t working right now...localhost didn’t send any data... ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"
